# Как настроить корректное сохранение скопированной информации в буфер системы Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ос

Пользуюсь системой Linux Ubuntu 19.10. У меня такая проблема : при копировании какого-то текста из файла я его могу его вставить куда требуется только до закрытия данного файла. Если я копирую текст, а потом закрываю файл, то буфер очищается и информация пропадает, вставить ее куда-то уже не предоставляется возможным. Можно ли каким-то образом настроить поведение подобное Windows? Чтобы я мог копировать и даже после закрытия источника копирования информация не стиралась из буфера ?

Comment: Нет, ведь в linux отсутствует системное api работы с буфером обмена, так что многие программы используют самопальные способы. Попробуйте копировать разными способами.

Comment: @user7860670 печально. Это настолько неудобно, особенно привыкнув к такому  в Windows.((

Comment: @user7860670 вроде бы прогуглил, что есть менеджеры для буфера обмена. Сейчас попробуем

Comment: Можно привыкнуть не закрывать документ, пока не выполнишь "вставить". Работает и в Windows и в Linux

Comment: @ГерманБорисов самый бесполезный совет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В линуксе есть два буфера обмена. Буфер выделения (ещё называется primary) и буфер "обычный". То, что Вы описываете в вопросе очень похоже на него. Текст достаточно выделить, а в новом месте нажать среднюю кнопку мыши (или <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> Но если файл закрыть, то выделение пропадает (это логично) и в буфере уже ничего нет.

Второй буфер работает так как Вы привыкли в Windows. И обычно все работает через привычные <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>. К сожалению, не все приложения умеют так. Тот же терминал по нажатию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> посылает сигнал приложению sigint. Но в убунте обычно работает <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Использование менеждера буфера обмена позволяет очень гибко настроить это поведение. У меня к примеру настроено так, что буфер не теряется даже после перезагрузки. Можно объеденить эти два буфера, что бы они работали синхронно. Также там бывают разнообразные дополнения, которые часто нужны (к примеру - выделил имя тикета в джире - предлагает перейти на нее)

Comment: Ну вот, я добился нужного мне эффекта включением в KDE "Clipboard". Изначально не понял что это за штука да и выключил ее. Теперь как-то стал замечать неудобства при копировании/вставке, которое впрочем и описал в вопросе. Теперь всё отлично работает, вроде бы около 6 последних копирований хранит + последнее доступно для вставки, наверное и после перезагрузки также.  Так что проблема решилась. Если не секрет, то каким менеджером буфера пользуетесь вы ? Кстати, да, только теперь заметил, что copy/paste на мышку и ctrl+c/ctrl+v хранят данные в разных буферах.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной проблемы можно попробовать использовать менеджеры буфера обмена. В моем случае помогло включение CLipboard от KDE. Так же есть неплохая статья о менеджерах буфера обмена [ссылка](https://losst.ru/luchshie-menedzhery-bufera-obmena-linux)